# Exporting result of a stored procedure to a CSV file

Tags: sql, sql-server, export-to-csv

I have a very old software that I need to update. The software itself is written in VB6 and now I need to build a stored procedure on SQL Server and output the result of the stored procedure to a `.csv` file. What is the best approach to this problem?

Should I setup some sort of job on the database which exports it to `.CSV`? Or should I fetch the results from within the software and in the software build the `.CSV` file?

Personally I'd rather use a db job if that's possible, but is that what you would do? It was a really long time ago I was working in VB6 and that is the reasoning behind doing it server-side, but if you guys prefer the other way (or even a third way) I'd consider that instead.

All light on this is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at SSIS (SQL Server Integration Services)? It allows you to easily create a "package" (SQL Agent Job) that exports data on a predefined schedule. CSV is one of the output options and it allows a great degree of flexibility. SSIS isn't loaded by default with a SQL install, so this might not be an option for you if you don't have enough permissions, but if you have or can get it installed it's great for this.

EDIT:
If you're interested in a closer look, this page has a step by step with pictures http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/70/Posts/18873/exploring-ssis-export-to-csv-file.aspx it's about 15 minutes worth of clicking and typing for the complete solution, though of course it takes much longer the first time as you get used to the interface.

It's also very extensible, if you decide later you need to manipulate files or directories, run a stored procedure, or set flags in your database it can do all of that in a package too - just make sure your SQL Agent account or whatever proxy your job runs under has permissions on the tables, files, directories, etc. you are manipulating.

Comment: Sounds very interesting! I do have limited permissions but I'll definitely look into this! I'm guessing this is kinda the standard when doing this nowadays?

Comment: @david-larsson it's one very common way, it provides a flexible, reliable, and secure way to import/manipulate/export data. It's very easy to use in its most basic form, but you can create very powerful solutions if you need to. It's definitely my first choice for this type of problem, but there are others that will work too.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to mess with VB, MSSQL server has a "Export and Import Wizard". Depending of your SQL server version, it's somewhere in SQL Server menu/icons. You can choose between csv and Excel format, plus many other formats.

If "Export and Import Wizard" is not adequate for your problem, you can use SSIS (SQL Server Integration service). It's also bundled with SQL Server. It gives you more power, but it's more complicated.

Basically, the most complicated part is to write stored procedure. Exporting data is easy with above mentioned tools.